# Error converting text "0" to numeric 0

Tags: r, csv

I have a very large key value dataset that I imported from a CSV file like this and reshaped into a very long table:

```
#read in suitability data file
allapp <- read.csv(file="Dist.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

#clip and reshape key values into a table
appdata <- subset(allapp, grepl("^SUIT*", allapp$XmlKey))
appdata <- select(appdata, TransIdentifier, XmlKey, XmlValue)
appdata <-spread(appdata, XmlKey, XmlValue)
```

All fields came in as text values. When I convert a column to numeric values, all non-zero fields convert properly:

```
#Income & expense analysis - source
appdata <- rename(appdata, Monthly_Income = SUIT42)
appdata$Monthly_Income <- as.numeric(appdata$Monthly_Income)
```

However, for some reason, every "0" is converted into the number 71. 
When I write the tables to a csv file, the "0"s look normal:

```
  "0","100000","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",NA,"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",NA,"0","0","false",NA,
```

Any idea why?

Comment: try: appdata$Monthly_Income <- as.numeric (as.character(appdata$Monthly_Income)).  Most likely the values were imported as factors, in which case you will have to convert to a character and then into a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks so much. That solved it. Guess I need understand the sequence of conversions of variables better,

Comment: This is a very common mistake, it has burned every R user at least once.  Here is an good reference to get started:  http://www.cookbook-r.com/ Chapter 6. Manipulating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
appdata$Monthly_Income <- as.numeric (as.character(appdata$Monthly_Income))
```